# xfs, it is possible to disable the log?

Tags: logging, disk, diskimage, xfs

I'd like to disable log in the xfs.

I didn't find an option in

`mkfs.xfs`

So my question is: Is it possibile to disable them or move them in RAM?
If yes, how?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You cannot disable the logging code paths in xfs, but you can remove any actual IO overhead by using some dirty tricks (note, I have not tested this beyond mounting it):

```
# modprobe null_blk
# mkfs.xfs -l logdev=/dev/nullb1,size=16m <DATA_DEVICE>
# mount -o logdev=/dev/nullb1 <DATA_DEVICE> <MOUNT_POINT>
```

Of course by doing this you lose all consistency guarantees that the log would give you, and after a crash or power loss you will need to run xfs_repair to make the filesystem consistent again.

Answer (score 2):

The xfs filesystem is a journal filesystem so no you cannot disable logging entirely.(i'm not sure why you would). The `mkfs.xfs -l [log_section_options]` will allow you to shrink the size of the log or move it to another device. You may do something like this : `mkfs.xfs -l size=512b /dev/sdc1` to shrink the log file to the minimum size allowed.

Comment: but can I move it in RAM? Thank you for your reply

Comment: I would recommend reading the documentation, I am not an expert on xfs. If i had to wager a guess i would say no because RAM is volatile memory and that would defeat the point of logging.

Comment: The reason you would want to is because it's super buggy and prone to allocation deadlocks where trivial IO ops can block for a long time because they get put on a wait list behind long running ops.